# HAProxy как разделить бекенды в зависимости от пути

Tags: proxy, маршрутизация, балансировка

Есть набросок такой конфигурации для HAProxy:

```
defaults
  log global
  mode http
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 5000
  timeout server 5000

frontend main
  bind *:80
  acl is_redmine path_beg /redmine
  use_backend redmine_back if is_redmine

backend redmine_back
  server redmine_server redmine:3000
```

Как мне переадресовать запросы на redmine (это контейнер) и получать ответы с таким путем "**some_adress/redmine/login**"?

Сейчас на redmine кидает запросы вместе со словом "redmine". Пример логов для понимания, у redmine нет обработки **0.0.0.0:3000/redmine**:

```
redmine_1  | [2021-06-11 18:35:05] INFO  WEBrick 1.6.1
redmine_1  | [2021-06-11 18:35:05] INFO  ruby 2.7.3 (2021-04-05) [x86_64-linux]
redmine_1  | [2021-06-11 18:35:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=3000
redmine_1  | 172.18.0.4 - - [11/Jun/2021:18:35:11 UTC] "GET /redmine HTTP/1.1" 404 459
redmine_1  | - -> /redmine
```

Я хочу что бы к нему пришел запрос без редмайна.

Есть у кого пример конфигурации рабочей или куда читать?

Заранее спасибо.

### Update 1

Такое решение помогло, но создало новую проблему:

```
http-request set-path "%[path,regsub(^/redmine,/,i)]"
```

После ответа, страница пытается подгрузить статичный контент, но без пути **redmine**, т.е. `http://some_addres/stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1.css?1619448608`,

а хотелось бы `http://some_addres/`**redmine/**`stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1.css?1619448608`

### Update 2

Я дошел до переадресаций и это работало, но баговало, конечно. Вот пример конфигурации, мб кому именно так нужно будет делать, НО **не рекомендую**:

```
frontend main
  bind *:80
  acl is_redmine path_beg -i /redmine
  acl is_redmine_referer hdr(Referer) -i -m sub /redmine
  http-request redirect location http://%[req.hdr(host)]/redmine%[path]?%[query] if !is_redmine is_redmine_referer
  use_backend redmine_back if is_redmine
  use_backend redmine_back if is_redmine_referer

backend redmine_back
  http-request set-path "%[path,regsub(^/redmine,/,i)]"
  server redmine_server redmine:3000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему ГОРАЗДО проще, создал несколько сабдоменов наподобие redmine.somename.ru и, предположим, wiki.somename.ru.

Настроил переадресацию отталкиваясь от хоста, работает как часы.

Пример конфигурации:

```
frontend main
  bind *:80
  acl is_redmine hdr(Host) -i -m sub redmine.
  use_backend redmine_back if is_redmine

backend redmine_back
  server redmine_server redmine:3000
```